# Flutter hive data is shown after restarting the app on android

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am using latest version of hive and hive_flutter. On background handler when notification is received i save the data in hive box. But it is not shown in the app when i restart the application then the box show the data.

I am using below code to read the data from the box.

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: Boxes.getConnections().listenable(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, Box<Connections> box, _) {
            final connection = box.values.toList();
},)
```

In the main function i am using below code

```
 await Hive.initFlutter();
  if (Hive.isAdapterRegistered(0) == false) {
    Hive.registerAdapter(ConnectionsAdapter(), override: true);
  }

  if (Hive.isBoxOpen('connection_box') == false) {
    print('already close');
    await Hive.openBox<Connections>('connection_box');
  }
```

Comment: The title should be - "Flutter hive data is NOT shown..."

Answer (score 0):

Spent 8 hours trying to find where the problems is.
And it seems like the issue was in the always opened collection.

My WRONG usage steps:

1. Open a collection `final collection = await BoxCollection.open...`
2. Get a box `final box = await collection.openBox(boxName);`
3. Get data from the box `final data = await box.get('dataKey');`(In my case I didn't have any data yet in the box)
4. Another method opens the collection again.
5. Gets the box.
6. Puts some data to the box `box.put('dataKey', 'data string')`;

To fix this, after the step 3, close the collection `collection.close()`

Comment: hive box will be depreciated soon according to the author. We should not use it

Comment: What should be the alternative if hive box is deprecated ?